# Docusaurus import @site alias unresolved in IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, webpack, docusaurus

I just created a Typescript Docusaurus website.

I know docusaurus has webpack aliases for React components imports (@site, etc), but IntelliJ cannot recognise these imports: i.e. Ctrl+B on the type won't go to source, and a red squiggle marks an error.

[image]

Is there a way to make IntelliJ ignore these prefixes and make it understand where the component is? AFAIU it's supposed to ignore the @site string all together, and all imports should work.

I did follow the [official instructions](https://docusaurus.io/docs/typescript-support) and after creating the site, I added the tsconfig.json and the exta types package as recommended, but to no avail:

```
$ cat tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/docusaurus/tsconfig.json"
}
$ grep tsco package.json
    "@tsconfig/docusaurus": "^1.0.5",
$
```

## EDIT

I recreated the project from scratch:

```
$ npx create-docusaurus@latest mytest --typescript

$ yarn add --dev typescript @docusaurus/module-type-aliases @tsconfig/docusaurus

$ cat tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/docusaurus/tsconfig.json"
}
```

yarn run build works OK, everything OK, just IntelliJ is marking @site imports as errors the SAME way.

This is the relevant config:

[image]
and:
[image]

I've tried the bundled Typescript binary as well, but same result.

## EDIT 2:

VSCode has the same identical issue: it's a problem within the repository, not with IntelliJ.

[image]

At this point, I completely ran out of ideas, any pointers anyone? :(

Answer (score 2):

works fine here

[image]

please make sure that both `@docusaurus/module-type-aliases` and `@tsconfig/docusaurus` packages are installed

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/module-type-aliases": "2.0.0-beta.20",
    "@tsconfig/docusaurus": "^1.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
```

and that your `tsconfig.json` current file is included in extends the `@tsconfig/docusaurus/tsconfig.json`:

```
 "extends": "@tsconfig/docusaurus/tsconfig.json"
```

Comment: Thanks for testing, but after creating a fresh project from scratch, I still experience the same issue.

Comment: See my edit, at this point I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

My project's tsconfig.json was supposed to "extend" the docusaurus' tsconfig.json, but it never really picked it up apparently.

In order to fix my issue I had to actually copy all the content of the Docusaurus' tsconfig.json file and paste it in my project's tsconfig.json.

I.e. now my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Docusaurus v2",
  "docs": "https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/typescript-support",
  
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["DOM"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": ["node", "@docusaurus/module-type-aliases", "@docusaurus/theme-classic"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@site/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

While this does not work:

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/docusaurus/tsconfig.json"
}
```

So we can say the "extend" clause in tsconfig.json does not work for some reason. I do not know the reason though.